# Create subgroup for project with similar name

Tags: gitlab

I have a project which is hosted under a group and I just realized that this project grew quite large so it would fit a subgroup (also because there are multiple aspects to this project). Now I want to use a subgroup that has a similar name as the project has right now and then splitting the project further within this subgroup.

Suppose the project is hosted at `Group/Project` and I want to split it into two parts called `Foo` and `Bar`. They should be hosted under `Group/Project/Foo` and `Group/Project/Bar` respectively where `Project` is now a subgroup of `Group`.

When I try to create the subgroup `Project` it fails because that name is already taken by the project. What would be the correct way to proceed? Do I have to move the project to some temporary placeholder name, then create the subgroup, then move the project to that subgroup and then rename it?